# Searching multiple Super Table columns against an established value

Tags: search, plugin-supertable

I currently have three global Super Table fields, `global.berkeleyDeliveryMatrix`, `global.oaklandDeliveryMatrix` and `global.sanFranciscoDeliveryMatrix`, all of which have a plaintext column in them titled `zipCode`. [image]

The user has a profile address saved, which I'm looking to check against on the `userZip` field.

How could I search against all three of the global fields and return either a true or false statement if the set zip code was matched against any of the rows in the globals?